# Unity mobile Multiple touches

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a mobile game that detects where the player is pressing on the screen for the character to move accordingly, if the player puts another finger anywhere else... in my case the jump button the character stops moving, I suspect this is because my code detects multiple touches and does not know how to handle it, I tried a few things but nothing worked for me, any ideas how to code a way so that if at least one touch is in the area I want it will keep moving and will not be disturbed by other touches? Thanks in advance!!

```
private void Start()
    {
        screenWidth = Screen.width;
        screenHeight = Screen.height;
    }

private void Update()
        int i = 0;
        while (i < Input.touchCount)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);

                positionX = touch.position.x;
                positionY = touch.position.y;
                if (touch.position.x < screenWidth / 6 && touch.position.y < screenHeight /2)
                {
                    PlayerController.StopMoving();
                    PlayerController.MoveLeft();
                }
                else if (touch.position.x > screenWidth / 6 && touch.position.x < screenWidth / 2 && touch.position.y < screenHeight /2) 
                {
                    PlayerController.StopMoving();
                    PlayerController.MoveRight();
                } else
                {
                    PlayerController.StopMoving();
                }
            ++i;
        } if (Input.touchCount == 0)
        {
            PlayerController.StopMoving();
        }
```

Player controller is a seperate script responsible for the movements, this script is the one that activates those movements

This is what my game looks like, Though it might help, the move buttons are only UI while the jump and shoot are actual buttons[image]

Comment: is there a reason you did want to use Buttons: https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html  it would really simplify your logic.

Answer (score 0):

An "invalid" touch no matter what will stop your character. I would remove the `else` branch in the `while`. If you have a valid touch, your character moves, if you don't have any, `Input.touchCount == 0` will stop the movement.

You can also cache some of your variables to avoid some calculations, and both left and right movement calls stop, so its logic should move into `MoveLeft` and `MoveRight` in `PlayerController`.

Something like this should do what you want:

```
private float _leftXMax;
private float _rightXMax;
private float _yMax;

private void Start()
{
    _leftXMax = Screen.width / 6;
    _rightXMax = Screen.width * 0.5f;
    _yMax = Screen.height * 0.5f;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount == 0)
    {
        PlayerController.StopMoving();
        return;
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (i < Input.touchCount)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
        if (touch.position.y > _yMax) continue;

        float positionX = touch.position.x;
        if (positionX < _leftXMax) PlayerController.MoveLeft();
        else if (positionX < _rightXMax) PlayerController.MoveRight();
    }
}
```

In this case, the last valid touch determines the character's movement.
This can be done in a lot of ways, according to what you want to achieve, so I followed your logic here.